# как возвести cos в квадрат в пайтоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Надо сделать калькулятор для решения такого примера: cos^2(sin 1/z). но pow не работает. Поясните, как можно решить эту задачку?

Comment: Слова "сделать калькулятор" не ясны. Что на входе, что вы хотите на выходе увидеть? Связанный вопрос [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так?

```
# cos^2(sin 1/z)

from math import cos, sin

z = 3
result = cos(sin(1 / z)) ** 2
print(result)  # 0.8967098683878832
```

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @ВладСоловьев, мой код работает, а почему в вашем коде ошибка я не могу знать (в вопросе вы ведь не добавили свой код). А так, ошибка говорит о том, что `z` у вас это строка, поэтому добавьте превращение в `int`: `z = int(z)`, или в самой формуле `z` замените на `int(z)`

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы.

Comment: @ВладСоловьев, хорошо, тогда отметьте ответ как правильный